# Update record if exists else post in node/express app

Tags: node.js, express

I have written a Restful API using Node/Express and Mongo. I need to code an endpoint where if an email address for a user exists, I update their record. If it does not, then I need to create a new record.

I'm not sure how to do this...

Do I use a post or put method?

Comment: Following the docs, PUT is to either update or create a resource, while POST, is just to create. To answer you should use a PUT for your problem

Comment: Thanks franckstifler! Is that all I have to do, is change my .post to .put? Which docs are you looking at?

Comment: it should be noted that it's just a convention, and either `POST` or `PUT` will work. To do create or update depending on if the record already exists, you should use mongo's upsert functionality, see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/.

Comment: https://www.google.cm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt4-_xqcrUAhUDnRoKHQeoCH4QFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F630453%2Fput-vs-post-in-rest&usg=AFQjCNGl4gIU5q2SzpYtMy-RY0L_0OfhTw&sig2=mTTDVmQpDv7m45cV5sYqHA The real deal actually is not the method, but the implementation of your code into the route. You might still use a POST for a PUT, but... you are not doing REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, which is conceptually simplest, is to make a `find` query, and limit to 1. If you find something and don't have null, then do `x`, else do `y`. So you'd have an if statement in that approach. This is good if you just have a single field you are checking.

Another way is to use the `$exists` operator to get the correct records. So for records where the email is null, just pass in `$exists: null` for the email field. More info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). This is good if you are checking more than one field.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Really don't see how this answers his problem.

Comment: @franckstifler well he said he wasn't sure how to do this. You answered the the PUT/POST question, I gave an overview to the rest of it